# Swagger JAX-RS APIParam Header Data-Type

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I'm trying to automatically generate a custom data type for my header field. For this I'm defining my header as follows:

```
public String foo(
    @ApiParam(value = Documentation.HEADER_SERVICE, required = true)
    @HeaderParam(Services.HEADER_SERVICE)
    Service service) {
    ...
}
```

However, the generated swagger file results in a definition with scheme "string" for the Service-Header. Now I understand, that header fields can only be of type string, however I'd like to include the (json) structure of the service header in the documentation.

How can I achieve this?

I also tried `@ApiImplicitParam`, however, the scheme only includes the defined string, instead of a reference to the model.